# Disable <li> tag contents using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
{
    if(inputs[i].id.indexOf(startsWith) == 0) {
        eles.push(inputs[i].id);
    }
}
for(var j=0; j < eles.length; j++) {
    document.getElementById(eles[j]).setAttribute("class","jstree-checked");                
}
```

Am taking out the ids that starts with certain pattern in the `li` tags of my document.
I am changing the class of the `li` tags of the resulting ids.
I also need to disable the contents present in the `li` tag as a whole.
Is it possible to do this using javascript or jquery?

**UPDATE:**
I've a checkbox and text message inside each `<li>` tag.
 Need to disable the checkbox(non clickable) and display the text as disabled.

```
<li id="1_1" class="jstree-leaf jstree-no-icons jstree-last jstree-leaf jstree-unchecked" crawllocation="D:\company\deploy\AppServer\fusionEAR.ear" name="fusionEAR.ear">
<ins class="jstree-icon"> </ins>
<a class="" href="#" style="">
<ins class="jstree-checkbox"> </ins>
<ins class="jstree-icon "> </ins>
fusionEAR.ear
</a>
</li>
```

Tried these:

```
for(var j=0; j < eles.length; j++){
//jQV6('#jstreeDivforBrowse').jstree("check_node","#"+eles[j]);
document.getElementById(eles[j]).setAttribute("class","jstree-default jstree-checked");
//$.jstree._reference('#jstreeDivforBrowse').set_type("disabled", "#"+eles[j]); -- First try to disable
//eles[j].disabled = true;-- Second try to disable
//$("#"+eles[j]).attr('disabled', 'true');-- Third try to disable
//$("#"+eles[j]).addClass("jstree-leaf jstree-no-icons jstree-last jstree-leaf jstree-checked").find(":input").attr("disabled", "disabled");-- Fourth try to disable
        }
```

In any of these tries I couldnt find my checkbox disabled. But the task of selecting the check box is successful for required ids by changing the class name inside the loop as given.

Comment: What does it mean to disable contents?

Comment: I've a checkbox and text message inside each <li> tag. Need to disable the checkbox and display the text as disabled.

Comment: I'm not seeing a checkbox in your html

Comment: Its a checkbox that is generated by jstree automatically. hence only class name is there I suppose.

Comment: Further more can you provide an example of in ID that would be disabled and one that would not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [types plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/types) can be used to customize the nodes in jstree.

```
 types: {
    "disabled": {
        "select_node": false,
        "open_node":   false,
        "close_node":  false,
        "create_node": false,
        "delete_node": false
    }
}
```

Note we defined a `Type` and named it as `disabled`, so we have add the attribute `rel` as `disabled` to the `<li>` element to make it disabled. This is how jsTree look for `type` using the `rel` attribute.

with the `Type` being declared, in your loop just add,

```
document.getElementById(eles[j]).setAttribute("rel","disabled");
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: what if there are multiple childs of li?

Comment: @Cris you can find the number of childs using 'document.getElementById(inputs[0].id).childNodes.length' and traverse using the '[]' notation.

Comment: @Cris i have updated the fiddle as well. the jquery code will check if it has multiple checkbox elements

Comment: @LGAP I just checked the fiddle and it seems to work fine. could you please throw some light on the case it failed?

Comment: @LGAP updated the fiddle.Could you please check and let me know if the code helps

Comment: Sorry! Still its not working. the problem is I do not have any input boxes inside my `<li>` tag. Refer my html so that you might get some clue.

Comment: @LGAP sorry I was really not getting your point earlier.I understood that jstree does not actually give u the checkboxes :). check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487305/jstree-disable-checkbox) relative to our topic, also they have mentioned about the types plugin. have a look at this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/4fTDq/13/)

Comment: @LGAP  the "rel" attribute in the 'li' element need to be set as 'disabled'.I have tried this and its working. eg '<li rel="disabled">'. This attribute produces the desired result. I am updating my answer too. finally the solution is in place :)

Comment: Thanks Mahavel. But i am not sure where exactly should i place that types : "default".... stuffs. Can you see the pastebin and let me know?

Comment: I placed it correctly now and its working as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

use  `$("/* li element*/").attr("disabled", "disabled");` to disable it

or  `$("/* li element*/").hide();`  to hide it

in your case

```
for(var j=0; j < eles.length; j++) {
$("#"+eles[j]).addClass("jstree-checked").find(":input").attr("disabled", "disabled");

}
```

Comment: can you give me the exact line that would work on seeing my code. I am not aware of jquery.

Comment: which type of elements you want to disable? i.e input,select etc

Comment: @Cris glad that you are not aware of jquery :)