# jsTree disable checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jstree

I am using jsTree latest version in one of my application.
I want certain checkboxes to be disabled by default.
For that i am referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487305/jstree-disable-checkbox).

I have following jstree code:

```
$("#"+"div_"+aspectid).jstree({ 
                    'core' : {
                        "themes" : { "icons" : false },
                        'data' : {
                            'url' : 'include/ajax.php?option=constructtree',
                            'data' : function (node) {
                                return { aspectcode : aspectcode, geographylevel : geographylevel }; 
                                } 
                            }
                        },
                       "types" : 
                    {
                        "types" : {
                            "disabled" : {
                                 "check_node" : false, 
                                 "uncheck_node" : false 
                            }
                        }
                    },
        "plugins" : ["themes","html_data","ui","crrm","types", "checkbox"],
                    "checkbox" : { "two_state" : true }
                    });
```

I have added rel=disabled in the li tags

```
<li id=$childvalue[code] rel='disabled'>
```

I am not getting any errors and i am able to check and uncheck the node.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

provide filddler for same.

Inorder to disable check box and make it not to check and uncheck use "onclick= return false"

Answer (score 0):

This functionality has been changed in more recent versions of jstree.

With 3.2, to disable a checkbox set the data-jstree attribute on the LI tag.

```
<li data-jstree={ "checkbox_disabled": true }>
```